# Monitor history of USB flash drives

Tags: monitoring, usb-drive

I have to setup a monitoring system for our internet server, to monitor which USB Flash Drives (Pen Drives) are mounted and unmounted and when.(This is to avoid misuse, and to capture which unauthorized device is/was connected.)

Is there any method to monitor flash drive information such as : a) Serial Number, b) Make, c) Model, d) Capacity e) Label f) Time of mount/unmount etc., and store it, to view history about it?

I know there are number of commands to monitor currently mounted USB devices. Like `lsusb`,`lshw`. But how do I store that information.

Comment: You will have to disable the posibility of booting from usb, otherwise someone may be able to start his own OS in that machine and do whatever he wants without you knowing about that usb.

Answer (score 8):

Well, there is no ready-for-that software I know. But you can write your own script, which will be started when pendrive is inserted|removed from usb port. This script would be run by udev if you add this to `/etc/udev/rules/99-local.rules`:

```
ACTION=="add|remove", SUBSYSTEM=="block", KERNEL=="sd*", RUN+="/usr/local/bin/usb-add.sh"
```

and then in this script you will have following environment variables:

```
ACTION=add (or remove)
DEVLINKS='/dev/disk/by-id/usb-TDK_LoR_TF10_0703293903BE2444-0:0 /dev/disk/by-path/pci-0000:00:16.2-usb-0:1.1:1.0-scsi-0:0:0:0'
DEVNAME=/dev/sdf
DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:16.2/usb7/7-1/7-1.1/7-1.1:1.0/host14/target14:0:0/14:0:0:0/block/sdf
DEVTYPE=disk ← this is important to check in script
ID_BUS=usb ← this is important to check in script
ID_FS_TYPE=
ID_INSTANCE=0:0
ID_MODEL=TF10 ← model
ID_MODEL_ENC='TF10\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20'
ID_MODEL_ID=070a
ID_PART_TABLE_TYPE=dos
ID_PART_TABLE_UUID=686bc5da
ID_PATH=pci-0000:00:16.2-usb-0:1.1:1.0-scsi-0:0:0:0
ID_PATH_TAG=pci-0000_00_16_2-usb-0_1_1_1_0-scsi-0_0_0_0
ID_REVISION=PMAP
ID_SERIAL=TDK_LoR_TF10_0703293903BE2444-0:0
ID_SERIAL_SHORT=0703293903BE2444 ← serial number
ID_TYPE=disk
ID_USB_DRIVER=usb-storage
ID_USB_INTERFACES=:080650:
ID_USB_INTERFACE_NUM=00
ID_VENDOR=TDK_LoR ← vendor
ID_VENDOR_ENC='TDK\x20LoR\x20'
ID_VENDOR_ID=0718
```

You can examine the pendrive with:

```
fdisk -l ${DEVNAME}
```

to get capacity and partition layout.
And do various stuff like that. You can store information in file or in database. All is up to you.
You can even deny access to this device if you like by sending SCSI STOP UNIT and removing
the drive from system.

It is also important to check the `${ID_BUS}` to examine only usb devices.
It is important to check the `${DEVTYPE}` because the script will also be called for every partition on usb device:

```
DEVLINKS='/dev/disk/by-id/usb-TDK_LoR_TF10_0703293903BE2444-0:0-part1 /dev/disk/by-label/BACKUPS /dev/disk/by-path/pci-0000:00:16.2-usb-0:1.1:1.0-scsi-0:0:0:0-part1 /dev/disk/by-uuid/0FAA-E0EB'
DEVNAME=/dev/sdf1
DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:16.2/usb7/7-1/7-1.1/7-1.1:1.0/host18/target18:0:0/18:0:0:0/block/sdf/sdf1
DEVTYPE=partition
ID_BUS=usb
ID_FS_LABEL=BACKUPS ← filesystem label
ID_FS_LABEL_ENC=BACKUPS
ID_FS_TYPE=vfat
ID_FS_USAGE=filesystem
ID_FS_UUID=0FAA-E0EB
ID_FS_UUID_ENC=0FAA-E0EB
ID_FS_VERSION=FAT32
ID_INSTANCE=0:0
ID_MODEL=TF10
ID_MODEL_ENC='TF10\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20'
ID_MODEL_ID=070a
ID_PART_ENTRY_DISK=8:80
ID_PART_ENTRY_NUMBER=1
ID_PART_ENTRY_OFFSET=2048
ID_PART_ENTRY_SCHEME=dos
ID_PART_ENTRY_SIZE=15104000 ← size ;)
ID_PART_ENTRY_TYPE=0xc
ID_PART_ENTRY_UUID=686bc5da-01
ID_PART_TABLE_TYPE=dos
ID_PART_TABLE_UUID=686bc5da
ID_PATH=pci-0000:00:16.2-usb-0:1.1:1.0-scsi-0:0:0:0
ID_PATH_TAG=pci-0000_00_16_2-usb-0_1_1_1_0-scsi-0_0_0_0
ID_REVISION=PMAP
ID_SERIAL=TDK_LoR_TF10_0703293903BE2444-0:0
ID_SERIAL_SHORT=0703293903BE2444
ID_TYPE=disk
ID_USB_DRIVER=usb-storage
ID_USB_INTERFACES=:080650:
ID_USB_INTERFACE_NUM=00
ID_VENDOR=TDK_LoR
ID_VENDOR_ENC='TDK\x20LoR\x20'
ID_VENDOR_ID=0718
```

Maybe it is a good idea to limit access when `${DEVTYPE}=disk` but
store information about all partitions – `${DEVTYPE}=partition`.

HTH, Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can try searching for usb related information in **"/var/log/syslog"**.
This log file store an information each time you connect an usb device.
example when i connect an usb key :

```
Sep  3 09:02:00 LIMLD005 kernel: [ 1612.825433] usb 1-1.5: new high-speed USB device number 4 using ehci-pci
Sep  3 09:02:00 LIMLD005 kernel: [ 1612.919570] usb 1-1.5: New USB device found, idVendor=13fe, idProduct=5200
Sep  3 09:02:00 LIMLD005 kernel: [ 1612.919577] usb 1-1.5: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Sep  3 09:02:00 LIMLD005 kernel: [ 1612.919581] usb 1-1.5: Product: DataTraveler 111
Sep  3 09:02:00 LIMLD005 kernel: [ 1612.919584] usb 1-1.5: Manufacturer: Kingston
Sep  3 09:02:00 LIMLD005 kernel: [ 1612.919587] usb 1-1.5: SerialNumber: 485B39D31C4CECC0D0000450
Sep  3 09:02:00 LIMLD005 kernel: [ 1612.919885] usb-storage 1-1.5:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
Sep  3 09:02:00 LIMLD005 kernel: [ 1612.920043] scsi10 : usb-storage 1-1.5:1.0
Sep  3 09:02:00 LIMLD005 mtp-probe: checking bus 1, device 4: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.5"
Sep  3 09:02:00 LIMLD005 mtp-probe: bus: 1, device: 4 was not an MTP device
Sep  3 09:02:01 LIMLD005 kernel: [ 1613.918015] scsi 10:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Kingston DataTraveler 111 PMAP PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
Sep  3 09:02:01 LIMLD005 kernel: [ 1613.918513] sd 10:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg6 type 0
Sep  3 09:02:01 LIMLD005 kernel: [ 1613.919043] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdf] 60599040 512-byte logical blocks: (31.0 GB/28.8 GiB)
Sep  3 09:02:01 LIMLD005 kernel: [ 1613.919817] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdf] Write Protect is off
Sep  3 09:02:01 LIMLD005 kernel: [ 1613.919823] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdf] Mode Sense: 45 00 00 00
Sep  3 09:02:01 LIMLD005 kernel: [ 1613.921062] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdf] Write cache: disabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
Sep  3 09:02:01 LIMLD005 kernel: [ 1614.180902]  sdf: sdf1
Sep  3 09:02:01 LIMLD005 kernel: [ 1614.184007] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdf] Attached SCSI removable disk
Sep  3 09:02:02 LIMLD005 udisksd[2480]: Mounted /dev/sdf1 at /media/foobar/KINGSTON on behalf of uid 1000
```

All you have to do is writing a script to use those informations at your liking.
As the following command line, which will gives you basic informations :

```
grep usb-storage /var/log/syslog
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify the udev rules for USB device mounting and unmounting.

The mount rule will take the output from command like `udevadm info -a -n device_name ; date`

and unmounting rule will use the similar command for unmounting too.

*(I am not able to write the exact rules as of now, hence just giving the direction where you can make a move)*